# ¿Cómo se dice "I don´t know any alegrías falsetas" en español?

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras

¿Yo debería usar "no sé" o "no conozco" u otra palabra? 
¿Puedo decir "No conozco ningunas falsetas alegrías"?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "alegrías falsetas"? ¿Dónde lo has visto/oido?

Comment: @Yay https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falseta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alegr%C3%ADas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. If you are a guitar player and want to say that you don't know how to play any of them, then you should use *no sé*, or *no me sé*:

> No (me) sé ninguna falseta por alegrías.

If you want to say that you are not familiar or never heard any of them you can use *no conozco*:

> No conozco ninguna falseta por alegrías.

Answer (score 3):

El uso de las dos palabras es válido (`no sé` , `no conozco`) dependiendo del contexto en el que las quieras usar. En este caso para las palabras "alegrías falsetas" la traducción más precisa es, `no conozco alegrías falsetas`, dando a entender que no se ha experimentado una falsa alegría.

El uso de "ninguna" en `no conozco ningunas alegrías falsetas` es opcional, se agrega si se quiere hacer énfasis en que no conoces absolutamente ninguna.
También puedes decir `no conozco ninguna alegría falseta`. En los dos casos, con y sin plural, te refieres a lo mismo, pero sin plural tiene un sonido más claro al pronunciarse.